# How to avoid switch statement when input is not fixed?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have written below code

```
public enum ProcessEnums {
ASSIGNMENT, CREDIT,HOWMANY,HOWMUCH,ERROR;
}

public final class StringConstants {
    public static final String Error = "I have no idea what you are talking about";
    public static final String rgxAssignment = "^([a-z]+) is ([I|V|X|L|C|D|M])$";
    public static final String rgxCredits = "((?:[a-z]+ )+)([A-Z]\\w+) is (\\d+) ([A-Z]\\w+)$";
    public static final String rgxHowMany= "^how many ([a-zA-Z]\\w+) is ((?:\\w+ )+)([A-Z]\\w+) \\?$";
    public static final String rgxHowMuch = "^how much is ((?:\\w+[^0-9] )+)\\?$";
}
private ProcessEnums checkMessage(String line) {
    ProcessEnums flag = ProcessEnums.ERROR;
    String[] rgxArray = new String[] { rgxAssignment, rgxCredits,
            rgxHowMany, rgxHowMuch };
    for (int i = 0; i < rgxArray.length; i++) {
        Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(rgxArray[i]);
        Matcher mcher = ptn.matcher(line);
        if (mcher.matches()) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return ProcessEnums.ASSIGNMENT;

            case 1:
                return ProcessEnums.CREDIT;

            case 2:
                return ProcessEnums.HOWMANY;

            case 3:
                return ProcessEnums.HOWMUCH;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

As you can see I don't get fixed input in checkMessage API. How I can implement this without switch block. I already thought of using Map but I don't have any fixed identifier as input String.

**To be precise I am looking for solution where I don't have to iterate on the list of Enums**

Comment: Changing your question when you have upvoted answers is very bad etiquette.

Comment: I havent upvoted ans yet. When I saw your answer it was upvoted.

Comment: Very bad etiquette nonetheless. It means that the effort I put into the answer is basically wasted. And the effort the community put into reading your question and my answer is wasted. It further means that this question is useless for the future, which is the core design principle of SO. Please ensure that you never do this again.

Comment: @Sach It doesn't mean *you* upvoted the answers. Since there are answers with upvotes, changing the question invalidates them and the effort their authors put in.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code *in the `enum`*!!

```
public enum ProcessEnum implements Predicate<String> {
    ASSIGNMENT("^([a-z]+) is ([I|V|X|L|C|D|M])$"),
    CREDIT("((?:[a-z]+ )+)([A-Z]\\w+) is (\\d+) ([A-Z]\\w+)$"),
    HOWMANY("^how many ([a-zA-Z]\\w+) is ((?:\\w+ )+)([A-Z]\\w+) \\?$"),
    HOWMUCH("^how much is ((?:\\w+[^0-9] )+)\\?$");

    private final Pattern patt;

    ProcessEnum(final String regex) {
        this.patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean test(final String s) {
        return patt.matcher(s).matches();
    }
}
```

Now rewrite your code as:

```
private ProcessEnum checkMessage(String line) {
    return Arrays.stream(ProcessEnum.values())
            .filter(pe -> pe.test(line))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("I have no idea what you are talking about"));
}
```

Use an `Exception` for exceptional circumstances, don't use a marker value. `Exception`s exist for a reason.

This also allows you to add new patterns without changing the code is so many places.

Note the order of iteration will be the order of declaration, more specific patterns need to go first.

Finally, `ProcessEnum.values()` will return a new copy of the `ProcessEnum[]` with each invocation. You may want to to cache this in the `static final` variable for efficiency.

Comment: We are still iterating on every possibility? I was looking for solution where I  dont have to iterate on all enums

Comment: @Sach as your code relies on regex to detect what type the input is, there is no way around that - you have to iterate over your regex expressions and test each one. If you don't want to do that, you will need to rethink your core logic.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How can i resolve the issue on Java 6 or 7. There's no Lambda Expressions on the versions.

Comment: @TienNguyen write it without lambda expressions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: My basic requirement is I need to process the messages as they come in there is know definite value to string thats why I used regex. I have exhausted with approaches so thought to drop a question on this

Comment: @Sach there is no way around checking all the possibilities. You could do this in regex, with `((aaa)|(bbb))` and checking the captured group. That would almost certainly be slower, and much less readable.